# Concurrency with a REST API that uses JWT

Tags: python, concurrency

I am designing a solution that will perform concurrent http requests to certain REST API. Thing is that this API requires to make a POST request to an authentication endpoint (with username + api_key in the header) so that the server gives you a 20min valid JWT.

As far as I see whenever you ask for a new token, previous token is no longer valid.

In this scenario, is concurrency a possibility? (e.g. using multi-thread in python). As far as I understand, with that principle of working with JWT only one thread shall be doing the job, and not "n" number of threads concurrently, as each thread would invalidate previous token

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one thread which only manages the authentication, ie fetches a new JWT every 15 minutes (something under 20).

Create N worker threads which make the POST requests.

All threads should share a variable holding the JWT in use and a synchronization primitive like `threading.Event`. Where you want to store them (global, class, etc) is up to you.

The workers wait for this Event to be set via `ev.wait()` before every POST request.
The auth thread clear the event via `ev.clear()` when it needs to fetch a new JWT and when it has set the JWT variable, just set the Event again via `ev.set()`

This way the POST workers will run freely until the time to refresh the JWT, then pause only while a new one is being fetched.

This can also be done with `asyncio.Event` if you use async concurrency.

Comment: That solution sounds fantastic! What I thought was adding GCP PubSub and a Cloud Function (limiting the concurrency to one using a single instance) so that the system that makes these potential concurrent POST http requests do them to the pubsub queue, activating the cloud function (and hence, this cloud function would authenticate, make its job one at a time). I have added a sample screenshot to picture the situation